# htaccess redirect HTTP & HTTPS non-www to HTTPS www

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

How can I redirect my website from all HTTP requests to HTTPS and non-www HTTPS to HTTPS with www?

Example:

Redirect HTTP non-www, HTTP www. & HTTPS non-www:

`HTTP://example.com/` && `HTTP://www.example.com/` && `HTTPS://example.com/`

everything to HTTPS with www.:

`HTTPS://www.example.com/`

Comment: Do you have any redirects in place currently?  Is it just the one domain, or are there multiple names to deal with?

Comment: @ShaneMadden One domain. There are few redirects already in place like:
RewriteRule ^search search.php [L]
RewriteRule ^games/(.*).html?$ games.php?do=$1 [L]

Comment: What does your current virtual host config look like - one HTTP and one HTTPS, or different ones for www and non-www?  (`apachectl -S`)

Comment: I would like to do that redirects in single .htaccess file

Comment: Are you sure that's how you want to do this?  See [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#when).

Comment: @ShaneMadden Yes, I would like to do this in single .htaccess file if it's possible.

Comment: what framework are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# Redirect all "not correct" domain to www with https
# (is not important if comes with or without https):
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Redirect all non-ssl to ssl.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

I think this will work with your actual rules.

Comment: The last rule should ultimately be a 301 (permanent) redirect. So, `R` should be changed to `R=301` (otherwise it defaults to a 302 - temporary - redirect). The `NC` flag on the first condition should also be removed, since this is a _negated_ condition. Otherwise, it won't catch mix cased (malformed) `Host` headers.

Answer (score 0):

This will use for both www or non-www
If you try to open link with www then url redirect to https with www

```
Example : http://domain.com redirect to https://domain.com
```

or If you try to open link with non-www then url redirect to https with non-www

```
Example : http://www.domain.com redirect to https://www.domain.com

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This is only an HTTP to HTTPS redirect (same host). It does not canonicalise the www subdomain as requested in the question.